# InvalidDataContractException ("Type cannot be serialized") error using WCF DataContract

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, .net-4.0, datacontract

I need to pass [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (.NET Framework built-in type) in my data contract. Since this type cannot be serialized by itself, I derived my helper class from it:

```
[DataContract]
public class PhysicalAddressSerializable : PhysicalAddress
{
    public PhysicalAddressSerializable()
        : base(new byte[] {0,0,0,0,0,0})
    { }
    public PhysicalAddressSerializable(byte[] address) 
        : base(address)
    { }

    [DataMember]
    public string AddressString { get { return ToString(); } set { Parse(value); } }
}
```

It serializes to XML pefectly; however, when I try to pass it into service call, I'm getting System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException:

*Type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.*

Stack trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ClassDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteUnitInfoToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameters(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncoderFactory.BinaryMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.EncodeMessage(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnSendCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

Comment: What does `PhysicalAddress` look like?

Comment: It's a framework class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress(v=vs.100).aspx, sorry for not making it apparent! I.e. I don't have access to it, that's why I had to overload it in the first place.

Comment: in that case, I strongly suggest you use a DTO *instead of* anything related to `PhysicalAddress`

Comment: Looks like it's the way to go. Although, I still don't understand why wcf serializer even cares about base class, which has no public instance properties of its own.

Comment: well, the job of a serializer is to reconstruct the data you sent in; *most* serializers care about the subclass - although it is nice if they give you the choice. Sometimes they don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the error message, it is unhappy about `PhysicalAddress`, the base-class. So either:

- don't use the base-class - use a simple DTO that doesn't need it, or:
- mark the base-class for serialization

Specifically, something like:

```
[DataContract, KnownType(PhysicalAddressSerializable)]
public class PhysicalAddress {
    [DataMember(...)]
    public SomeType Foo {get;set;} // whatever
}
```

However! From the name `PhysicalAddressSerializable`, it sounds like you don't *want* to have the base-class as serializable. You could *try* using:

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public class PhysicalAddressSerializable : PhysicalAddress {...}
```

Comment: +1 However, I think it should be `... KnownType(typeof(PhysicalAddressSerializable)`.

Comment: The problem is, base class (`System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress`) is a Framework class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress(v=vs.100).aspx). Why serializer would even care about the base class (which even does not have public fields/properties to be serialized), when I'm providing it perfectly serializable derived class?

Comment: Regarding using `[XmlSerializerFormat]` - I tried it, same error.